# How do I use git diff -G?

Tags: git, msysgit, git-diff

I'm writing a little test suite that runs the tool to be tested over a bunch of input files. For each input file, a corresponding output file is being created by the tool (both are in XML). Input and output files are checked in on a Git repo.

The output files carry the time when the tool was compiled, so the output files are surely modified after they were re-created by the tool being tested.

To have a quick glimpse if the output has changed (when I modified the sources of the tool), I'd like to check whether the content of the node `OutputFingerprint` has changed (simple hash over the contents of the relevant parts of the output file).

Reading the manual for [`git-diff`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), I found that there's a `-G` option:

> **-G<regex>**
>   Look for differences whose added or removed line matches the given <regex>.

Unfortunately, they provide no example for how to use the `-G` option.

My first thought was to simply write

```
git diff -GOutputFingerprint
```

but that's wrong:

```
> git diff -GOutputFingerprint
error: invalid option: -GOutputFingerprint
```

Next thought was to put the regex in slashes, which is also not successful:

```
> git diff -G/OutputFingerprint/
error: invalid option: -GC:/Program Files/Git/OutputFingerprint/
```

Also, simply putting a space between `-G` and `OutputFingerprint` doesn't work:

```
> git diff -G OutputFingerprint
fatal: ambiguous argument 'OutputFingerprint': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions
```

When I call `git diff` without any params, I get the modification:

```
-    <OutputFingerprint>e45807ca76fc5bb78e9e928c6fb7eed6</OutputFingerprint>
+    <OutputFingerprint>d0846851bc9d52b37f7919def78660a2</OutputFingerprint>
```

Another thought was to use `git diff -S".*OutputFingerprint.*" --pickaxe-regex`, but this is also not successful.

`git --version` gives me `git version 1.7.3.1.msysgit.0` if that is relevant.

When I ask `git diff --help`, the provided manual shows me the `-G` option.

So, could anyone provide me an example for how to use `git diff -G` correctly?

Comment: Try adding a space between the `G` and the regex?

Comment: heh, my git 1.7.1 doesn't have the `-G` option -- I wonder if yours has `-G` support? You may need a newer version to support what you want to do.

Comment: just to make sure, are there actual changes to report? Without uncommitted changes, I got "unknown revision" sorts of errors even without the `-G`... Just make sure you get _some_ kind of diff before trying to filter it.

Comment: The syntax `git diff -G OutputFingerprint` is working for me on MacOSX, git version 1.7.4.1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git diff -Garegex
```

runs fine with msysgit 1.7.4, but only in a bash session (in a DOS session, it returns nothing)

It will display the `diff` if the regex matches a line *added* or *removed* from the staged version.
*added* or *removed*: **not changed**.
Meaning in your case, <del>**it won't work**</del>

The OP [eckes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/520162/eckes) reports it works (with msysgit1.7.4+ only), adding that the [`diff` man page](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff) for `-G` option includes:

> "Look for differences whose *added* or *removed* line matches the given regex",
> which relates to the diff output **where a changed line is printed as one added and one removed line**.

---

Example: I add a new line 'aaa' (without `git add`: just a simple edit)

```
$ git diff -Gaaa

diff --git a/conf/fragments/xxx_repos.conf b/conf/fragments/xxx_repos.coindex 263fa85..3475f9b 100644
--- a/conf/fragments/xxx_repos.conf
+++ b/conf/fragments/xxx_repos.conf
@@ -10,3 +10,4 @@ repo xxx-sdsfwk
     RW+                                = vonc user1 user2
     RW                                 = @xxx_users
 xxx-sdsfwk "Owner" = "for..."
+aaa
```

---

Note that with Git 2.33 (Q3 2021), using `--pickaxe-regex` (normally reserved for `-S`) won't be possible with `-G` (which already uses a regex anyway).

See [commit 5d93460](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d93460024541909337d6b08a8bec10b71caaf73), [commit 22233d4](https://github.com/git/git/commit/22233d43eb5479d1076e034eb5cdba973fa2b02a), [commit f97fe35](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f97fe358576c81d995843644ab58de1ebeb7fee9), [commit fa59e7b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fa59e7beb2a61d9cd1312b212075edf12935fdc6), [commit 9e20442](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9e204422985a518ac700889d1ca4d521b3a7bfb2), [commit a8d5eb6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a8d5eb6dc0d61625667b0d8155c425d3629baa12), [commit 5b0672a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5b0672a26e51387bc18adad89eaa3ebb131b2e33), [commit 5d35a95](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5d35a9531cc9af717383bc11c2dfa4edc020ac56), [commit 52e011c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/52e011cd2b13e00fe40b1d59986948330b61e030), [commit 2e197a7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e197a759221921d42c5e94ae3f4897cd456ebb4), [commit 03c1f14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/03c1f14acf5169d8e6c06a60c28ee5a6cfb9fd54), [commit d90d441](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d90d441c336cc120b47e025d14c3879864ce60c5), [commit 102fdd2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/102fdd2e07f72919060224b3eb3560524d6cf1f9), [commit a47fcbe](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a47fcbe6e412df295f1f5ffb8eca6dbe86d2b7bb), [commit d26ec88](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d26ec8800969ea1b692e0c87100dc4235cfa12e2), [commit 188e9e2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/188e9e28c5287f3f160b5f14e3e551b1c55c7301), [commit 7cd5d5b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7cd5d5b299497fb874897595c642144d7d894ee4), [commit 064952f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/064952fc34b9765282fec057b3af260eae7c75c6), [commit 69ae930](https://github.com/git/git/commit/69ae93089cd892d70429f7f06371860d65cb1f1b), [commit c960939](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c9609398580518dffaadaace17188c901a4a4522), [commit 6d0a401](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6d0a40166e87a78ca17fddeee25228ded92a169e), [commit ecbff14](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ecbff141a1c6e4a32a43f90db70cde2b2199b241) (12 Apr 2021) by [Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason (`avar`)](https://github.com/avar).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4da281e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4da281e84d87b099ba8d0a255534dc1251be968e), 13 Jul 2021)</sup>

> ### [`pickaxe`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/188e9e28c5287f3f160b5f14e3e551b1c55c7301): die when `-G` and `--pickaxe-regex` are combined
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Ævar Arnfjörð Bjarmason</sup>

> When the `-G` and `--pickaxe-regex` options are combined we simply ignore the `--pickaxe-regex` option.
> Let's die instead as suggested by our documentation, since `-G` is always a regex.
>
> When `--pickaxe-regex` was added in [d01d8c6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d01d8c6782850c18d62676dae3c72ad73be1e52e) ("Support for pickaxe matching regular expressions", 2006-03-29, Git v1.3.0-rc4 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/46e48c36043447b9739cdd7cae768dc53b5bc89d)) only the `-S` option existed.
> Then when `-G` was added in [f506b8e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f506b8e8b5fb231e63b69668b6b7516f12b32228) ("git log/diff: add -G that greps in the patch text", 2010-08-23, Git v1.7.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/b3c16ee454effda5ec8033ab665249710f622699)) neither the documentation for `--pickaxe-regex` was updated accordingly, nor was something like this assertion added.
>
> Since [5bc3f0b](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5bc3f0b56779d189aaf7cab7e5d307aa4e7c0887) ("diffcore-pickaxe doc: document -S and -G properly", 2013-05-31, Git v1.8.4-rc0 -- [merge](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71e120202fe073bd2e4e9db59ca01ab7c5e72f7e)) we've claimed that `--pickaxe-regex` should only be used with `-S`, but have silently tolerated combining it with `-G`, let's die instead.

Comment: @eckes: I have updated my answer with clarifications and an example. For changes, a believe a simple '`git diff | grep ...`' is enough ;)

Comment: Pointing me to msysgit 1.7.4 was the right way! `git diff -GOutputFingerprint` now shows me that `OutputFingerprint` was **changed**. Exactly what I need. Thank you!

Comment: @VonC: falling back to `grep` would have been my alternative if I weren't able to do it with git means alone. But now, there's no need for that...

Comment: @eckes: even better that what I thought. Excellent.

Comment: @VonC: I think, you mis-interpreted the docs when you thought, it won't work: obviously, *Look for differences whose added or removed line matches the given regex* relates to the diff output where a changed line is printed as one **added** and one **removed** line...