# Filtering a diff with a regular expression

Tags: regex, git, diff

It seems that it would be extremely handy to be able to filter a diff so that trivial changes are not displayed. I would like to write a regular expression which would be run on the line and then pass it another string that uses the captured arguments to generate a canonical form. If the lines before and after produce the same output, then they would be removed from the diff.

For example, I am working on a PHP code base where a significant number of array accesses are written as `my_array[my_key]` when they should be `my_array["my_key"]` to prevent issues if a `my_key` constant is defined. It would be useful to generate a diff where the only change on the line wasn't adding some quotes.

I can't change them all at once, as we don't have the resources to test the entire code base, so am fixing this whenever I make a change to a function. How can I achieve this? Is there anything else similar to this that I can use to achieve a similar result. For example, a simpler method might be to skip the canonical form and just see if the input is transformed into the output. BTW, I am using Git

Comment: "I can't change them all at once, as we don't have the resources to test the entire code base," - unless you actually have constants which might be used as array keys you can safely replace `[key]` with `['key']` without much testing. testing every file for parse errors it not that much work; you can easily automate it using `find` and the command-line `php` binary.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: We may have constants that match keys - our codebase is huge!

Comment: Searching for `define(` could give you a list of all constants, then searching for `[nameofyourconstant` for all constants (again, easy to automate) would show you if/where they are used as array keys.

Comment: @ThiefMaster: That sounds like a really good solution. Regardless, I am interested in whether there is a way to filter diffs

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462538/how-to-grep-the-git-diff/76412336

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There does not seem to be any options to Git's [`diff`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-diff.html) command to support what you want to do. However, you could use the [`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` environment variable](http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html#_git_diffs) and a custom script (or any executable created using your preferred scripting or programming language) to manipulate a patch.

I'll assume you are on Linux; if not, you could tweak this concept to suit your environment. Let's say you have a Git repo where `HEAD` has a file `file05` that contains:

```
line 26662: $my_array[my_key]
```

And a file `file06` that contains:

```
line 19768: $my_array[my_key]
line 19769: $my_array[my_key]
line 19770: $my_array[my_key]
line 19771: $my_array[my_key]
line 19772: $my_array[my_key]
line 19773: $my_array[my_key]
line 19775: $my_array[my_key]
line 19776: $my_array[my_key]
```

You change `file05` to:

```
line 26662: $my_array["my_key"]
```

And you change `file06` to:

```
line 19768: $my_array[my_key]
line 19769: $my_array["my_key"]
line 19770: $my_array[my_key]
line 19771: $my_array[my_key]
line 19772: $my_array[my_key]
line 19773: $my_array[my_key]
line 19775: $my_array[my_key2]
line 19776: $my_array[my_key]
```

Using the following shell script, let's call it `mydiff.sh` and place it somewhere that's in our `PATH`:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
git diff-files --patch --word-diff=porcelain "${5}" | awk '
/^-./ {rec = FNR; prev = substr($0, 2);}
FNR == rec + 1 && /^+./ {
    ln = substr($0, 2);
    gsub("\\[\"", "[", ln);
    gsub("\"\\]", "]", ln);
    if (prev == ln) {
        print " " ln;
    } else {
        print "-" prev;
        print "+" ln;
    }
}
FNR != rec && FNR != rec + 1 {print;}
'
```

Executing the command:

```
GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF=mydiff.sh git --no-pager diff
```

Will output:

```
file05 /tmp/r2aBca_file05 d86525edcf5ec0157366ea6c41bc6e4965b3be1e 100644 file05 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 100644
index d86525e..c2180dc 100644
--- a/file05
+++ b/file05
@@ -1 +1 @@
 line 26662: 
 $my_array[my_key]
~
file06 /tmp/2lgz7J_file06 d84a44f9a9aac6fb82e6ffb94db0eec5c575787d 100644 file06 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 100644
index d84a44f..bc27446 100644
--- a/file06
+++ b/file06
@@ -1,8 +1,8 @@
 line 19768: $my_array[my_key]
~
 line 19769: 
 $my_array[my_key]
~
 line 19770: $my_array[my_key]
~
 line 19771: $my_array[my_key]
~
 line 19772: $my_array[my_key]
~
 line 19773: $my_array[my_key]
~
 line 19775: 
-$my_array[my_key]
+$my_array[my_key2]
~
 line 19776: $my_array[my_key]
~
```

This output does not show changes for the added quotes in `file05` and `file06`.  The external diff script basically uses the Git [`diff-files`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-diff-files.html) command to create the patch and filters the output through a [GNU `awk`](https://www.gnu.org/s/gawk/) script to manipulate it. This sample script does not handle all the different combinations of old and new files mentioned for [`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git.html#_git_diffs) nor does it output a valid patch, but it should be enough to get you started.

You could use [Perl regular expressions](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html), [Python `difflib`](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) or whatever you're comfortable with to implement an external diff tool that suits your needs.

Answer (score 11):

```
$ git diff --help

-G<regex>
    Look for differences whose added or removed line matches the given <regex>.
```

**EDIT**:

After some tests I've got something like

```
git diff -b -w --word-diff-regex='.*\[[^"]*\]'
```

Then I've got output like:

```
diff --git a/test.php b/test.php
index 62a2de0..b76891f 100644
--- a/test.php
+++ b/test.php
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
<?php

{+$my_array[my_key]+} = "test";

?>
diff --git a/test1.php b/test1.php
index 62a2de0..6102fed 100644
--- a/test1.php
+++ b/test1.php
@@ -1,3 +1,5 @@
<?php

some_other_stuff();

?>
```

Maybe it will help you. I found it here http://www.rhinocerus.net/forum/lang-lisp/659593-git-word-diff-regex-lisp-source.html and there is more information on this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5999495/using-an-alternate-diff-algorithm-in-git)

**EDIT2**:

```
git diff -G'\[[A-Za-z_]*\]' --pickaxe-regex
```

Comment: That actually didn't display any of the options for me. Are they the same as the normal diff?

Comment: @Casebash: see my question on that topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5088907/how-do-i-use-git-diff-g

Comment: +1 for being interesting, but it isn't quite what I'm looking for

Comment: I've found `--word-diff-regex` param so maybe it will be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this is very interesting. It shows all changes to a word that either originally matched the pattern or was changed to match that pattern with all other changes treated as whitespace changes. So it is a better solution than -G<regex> when you want to see only changes matching a pattern, but still doesn't solve the filtering problem

Answer (score 11):

[grepdiff](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grepdiff) can be used to filter the hunks in the diff file.

```
$ git diff -U1 | grepdiff 'console' --output-matching=hunk
```

It shows only the hunks that match with the given string "console".

Answer (score 5):

from my own git --help

> --word-diff-regex=`<regex>`
>
> Use `<regex>` to decide what a word is, instead of considering runs of non-whitespace to be a word. Also implies --word-diff unless
>              it was already enabled.
>              Every non-overlapping match of the `<regex>` is considered a word. Anything between these matches is considered whitespace and
>              ignored(!) for the purposes of finding differences. You may want to append `|[^[:space:]]` to your regular expression to make sure
>              that it matches all non-whitespace characters. A match that contains a newline is silently truncated(!) at the newline.
>              The regex can also be set via a diff driver or configuration option, see gitattributes(1) or git-config(1). Giving it explicitly
>              overrides any diff driver or configuration setting. Diff drivers override configuration settings.

Comment: I don't know how about you, but to my opinion, this should be the accepted answer. :)

Comment: After the earlier answers didn't quite work, I tried `git diff --word-diff-regex=^\s` and got exactly the result I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize the input files in a first step, then compare the normalized files. This gives you most control over the process. E.g. you might want to only apply the regexp to non-HTML parts of the code, not inside of strings, not inside of comments (or ignore comments altogether).
Computing a diff on the normalized code is the proper way to do such things; working with regexps on single lines is much more error-prone and at most a hack.

Some diff utilities such as e.g. `meld` allow hiding "insignificant" difference, and come with a set of default patterns to e.g. hide whitespace-only changes. This is pretty much what you want, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

I provided an answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63593719/2760299).

I made a git function to do this with the regex as the only input. Just enter this into your gitconfig (I used my global gitconfig) and use it with `git regexadd <regex>`.

```sh
[alias]
        regexadd = "!f() { git diff -U0 \
                | grepdiff -E $1 --output-matching=hunk \
                | git apply --cached --unidiff-zero; }; f"
```

Answer (score 0):

I use an approach that combines `git diff` and applying a regular expression matching on the results. In some testing code (PERL), I know that testing is successful when the `OutputFingerprint` stored in the resulting files of the tests has not changed.

First, I do a

```
my $matches = `git diff -- mytestfile`
```

and then evaluate the result:

```
if($matches =~ /OutputFingerprint/){
  fail();
  return 1;
}else{
  ok();
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -4):

If the goal is minimize trivial differences, you might consider our [SmartDifferencer](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/SmartDifferencer) tool.

These tools compare the language *syntax*, not the layout, so many trivial changes (layout, modified comments, even changed radix on numbers) are ignored and not reported.
Each tool has a full language parser; there's a version for many languages, including PHP.

It won't handle the example  $FOO[abc] as being "semantically identical" to $FOO["abc"], because they are not.  If abc actaully has a definition as as constant, then $FOO["abc"] is not semantically equivalent.