# How to grep the git diff?

Tags: git, grep, diff

Is there a way to show the git-diff filtered by a given pattern.

Something like

```
git grepdiff pattern

changed file
+++ some sentence with pattern
changed file 2
--- some other pattern
```

Unfortunately the simplest solution is not good enough

```
git diff | grep pattern 

+++ some sentence with pattern
--- some other pattern
# not an option as doesn't put the filename close to the match
```

I came with a workaround using awk

```
git diff | awk "/\+\+\+/{f = \$2}; /PATTERN/ {print f \$0} "
```

But would love to find out that there is a command for this.

Comment: Apparently github project named git-diff-grep does something completely different.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/35434714/2019549

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/628695/grep-within-a-git-diff-but-show-file-and-line-number is related

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Not sure but isn't `git diff -G <regex>` flag OK?

> -G < regex>
>
> ```
> Look for differences whose added or removed line matches the given <regex>.
> ```

Comment: that's not exactly what I am looking for, as I want to see only the lines, that match the pattern - not the whole diff of a files, that include the change with the pattern

Comment: then I guess there's no simpler solution as yours

Comment: At least git diff -G is a better first step than the full git diff.

Comment: My version does not have the -G flag. Was it removed?

Comment: From http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff: `Look for differences whose patch text contains added/removed lines that match <regex>.` which behaves very differently from the given answer.

Comment: Also useful to see which files were affected by the regex: `git diff -G <regex> --raw`

Comment: -G shows matches in the removed text as well, not just the added text.

Comment: @Jason you're right, that's what was asked in the question (a diff is additions and removals)

Comment: Is there a similar solution that will search *all* commits, whether or not they are on the current branch? I'm not that familiar with `git reflog`, but the docs don't have any mention of `-G`…

Answer (score 21):

Have you tried `git diff -S<string>` or `git diff -G".*string.*"`? Note that they are not equivalent, see [the documentation about pickaxe](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitdiffcore.html#_diffcore-pickaxe%3a_for_detecting_addition/deletion_of_specified_string) for what -S does.

Comment: `git diff -S<string>` worked for me, insofar as returning only the files within a diff, which had changes that matched the given string. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Another possibility would be to view the whole diff and search the output using the normal `less` commands (type `/` and then the pattern).

When you have `less` configured to show some lines before the match using `--jump-target=N`, this is pretty useful. Try it like this:

```
PAGER="/usr/bin/less --jump-target=10" git diff
```

This means that the match should be shown on line 10 (shows 9 lines of context above), which may be enough to also see the file name.

You can also use e.g. `--jump-target=.5` to make it position the match in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 7):

I use `git log -p`, which opens less (configurable, though), which in turn can be searched for with <kbd>/</kbd>. There's also `git log -S <searchword>`.

Comment: I am familiar with those - by I am not looking in the history, but in the current working changes.

Comment: Allright, then the same method (as robinst quoted) could be used. If you want the output, you could probably use a any library using libgit2 or gitgui/gitk.

Answer (score 5):

I think your approach to "grep" `diff` output is the best workaround.

You may improve your awk script by using sed:

```
colored="(^[\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z])"
marker="^$colored+diff"
pattern="^$colored+.*(\+|\-).*PATTERN"
git diff --color | sed -rn -e "/$marker/! H; /$marker/ ba; $ ba; b; :a; x; /$pattern/ p"
```

- `colored`: regex to match terminal colored lines
- `marker`: marker to match division from differents `diff` hunks, lines starting with colored "diff"
- `pattern`: pattern to search for, lines starting with colored "+" or "-" and containing "PATTERN"

This will print full diff hunks, with added or removed PATTERN, also maintaining useful colored output.

Note that `^[` in `colored` should be actual, literal `^[`. You can type them in bash by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>[</kbd>

Comment: excellent!! for anyone trying to type this in somewhere other than a bash shell (eg editing .sh file in IDE) you need to replace the `^[` like `colored=$'(\e\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z])'` and on macOS you also need to `brew install gnu-sed` and replace `sed --> gsed`

Comment: this and @Leon answers are the only answers which are not workarounds. A limitation: it prints the whole file diff not just the hunks that match.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a custom diff tool that allows grepping inside changes (but not the context):

**Usage**

`GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF="mydiff --grep foo" git diff`

This will output those lines in your changes that contain `foo` (including lines where `foo` disappeared because of your changes). Any grep pattern can be used instead of `foo`.

Each output line starts with the following prefix:

```
filename: oldlinenum: newlinenum|
```

The script can also be used without the `--grep` option, in which case it simply formats the full diff (i.e. providing full context) as described above.

**mydiff**

```
#!/bin/bash

my_diff()
{
    diff --old-line-format="$1"':%6dn:      |-%L'     \
         --new-line-format="$1"':      :%6dn|+%L'     \
         --unchanged-line-format="$1"':%6dn:%6dn| %L' \
         $2 $3
}

if [[ $1 == '--grep' ]]
then
    pattern="$2"
    shift 2
    my_diff "$1" "$2" "$5"|grep --color=never '^[^|]\+|[-+].\+'"$pattern"'.*'
else
    my_diff "$1" "$2" "$5"
fi

exit 0
```

Answer (score 3):

I have been using this with great satisfaction :)

```
grep -ri <MY_PATTERN> $(git diff 790e26393d --name-only)
```

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, a simple solution is:

```
git diff -U0 | findstr string
```

If you want grouping by filename, use this

```
FOR /F "usebackq delims==" %i IN (`git diff --name-only`) do git diff -U0 %~fi | findstr string
```

Answer (score 1):

This did the job for me, I hope it will help someone:

```
git diff | grep  -P '^\+|^\-'
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions offered didn't exactly fit my needs, this solved *my* issue.

```
(
    START_DIFF=abc123
    END_DIFF=123dcf 

    # loop over all the files that have changed inside the diff
    # you can add a `| grep '<ext>$'` to the end of `--name-only`
    # if you need to be more aggresive with the filtering / or 
    # make it go faster...
    for file in $(git diff $START_DIFF $END_DIFF --name-only); do
        # loop over every line of the diff FOR that file.
        while IFS= read -r line; do
            # prepend the file name to every line
            echo "$file:$line"
        done < <(git diff $START_DIFF $END_DIFF $file)
    done
) | grep what-youre-looking-for
```

I could not get the line numbers working, but I didn't really need them to get them to work. The prepended filename was enough for me.

---

My exact issue:

Find all the files that added either a `from __future__ import ..` or a `-*- coding: utf-8 -*-` out of 70+ files.

```
(
    START_DIFF=branch-a
    END_DIFF=HEAD
    for file in $(git diff $START_DIFF $END_DIFF --name-only); do
        while IFS= read -r line; do
            echo "$file:$line"
        done < <(git diff $START_DIFF $END_DIFF $file)
    done
) | grep ':+' | awk '(/import/ && /__future/) || (/coding/)'
```

The output looks like this:

```
....
app/tests/test_views.py:+# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
app/tests/test_views.py:+from __future__ import absolute_import
app/tests/test_views.py:+from __future__ import division
app2/tests/test_views.py:+from __future__ import division
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Ugly, potentially inaccurate, but might be enough to get by if you're just eyeballing it:

`git diff origin/master | grep -Eo "(^diff.*|some-keyword)"`

Where `file1.txt` contains `some-keyword` once, and `file3.txt` contains `some-keyword` 3 times:

Outputs:

```
diff --git a/path/to/file1.txt b/path/to/file1.txt
some-keyword
diff --git a/path/to/file2.txt b/path/to/file2.txt
diff --git a/path/to/file3.txt b/path/to/file3.txt
some-keyword
some-keyword
some-keyword
diff --git a/path/to/file4.txt b/path/to/file4.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another hacked-together script that produces slightly different formatting of the results, combining https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569950/1836776 and the original question. This will print filenames and lines that have changed in the diff, with the filename on the first line, and changes for the file on subsequent lines.

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Adapted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/50569950/1836776

if [[ $1 == '--help' ]]; then
  script=`basename "$0"`
  echo "USAGE"
  echo "  $script term [git diff parameters]"
  echo
  echo "DESCRIPTION"
  echo "  Searches git diff results for <term>, returning only lines that have changed"
  echo
  echo "EXAMPLES"
  echo "  - Search all changes from master in current branch for 'TODO':"
  echo "    $script TODO master..."
  echo
  echo "  - As above, with pagination (color support):"
  echo "    $script TODO master... | less -r"
  exit 1
fi

colored=$'(\e\[[0-9;]*[a-zA-Z])'
marker="^$colored+diff"
pattern="^$colored+.*(\+|\-).*$1"
shift
# Yeah, okay, both sed and awk for maximum dork here, feel free to combine!
git diff --color $* | sed -rn -e "/$marker/! H; /$marker/ ba; $ ba; b; :a; x; /$pattern/ p" | awk "/\+\+\+/{f = \$2 \":\\n\"}; /$pattern/ {print f \$0; f = \"\"}"
```

Searches look something like this (you'll have to imagine the beautiful red/green colors for the changes):

```
# ./git-diff-grep.sh TODO main...
b/tsconfig.json:
+ /* TODO: don't forget to update this */
b/README.md:
-# TODO: update instructions
-TODO: license
```