# How to get git diff within a regex?

Tags: git, diff, git-diff

I would like `git diff` to compare only within a regex. For example:

Contents of file at Revision A:

```
A 0 1 
A 1 1 2
A 0 1 2 3
A 1 1 2 3 4
```

Contents of file at Revision B:

```
B 0 1
B 0 1 2
B 1 1 2 4
B 1 1 2 4 8 16
```

I might want to ignore the first word (ie 'A' or 'B'), match the next two words, and ignore the rest of the line. In the above, only the second and third lines should be reported.

[How to grep the git diff?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462538/how-to-grep-the-git-diff) indicates that `git -G` used to do what I want but it's behavior has changed. Is there a way to get this to happen (short of doing something like `diff <(git show ... | awk ...) <(git show ... | awk ...)`)?

Comment: If you're comparing two files (not revisions), would it not make more sense to use diff?  Why involve git?

Comment: Sorry, the example was a bit misleading. I'm actually trying to compare two revisions. I'll fix the example to be more representative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

diff lets you change the format of the diff.  You want to change the *content*, and in a specialized way.  Using `diff`, `git show` and `awk` (or similar) to accomplish this is correct.  It follows the Unix philosophy of piping text between small tools.

What I would suggest is to set this up either as [a git command alias](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases) or write a shell script like `~/bin/git-column-diff`.  Then you can `git column-diff file1 file2`.

You *could* abuse [the textconv feature](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html) to do the filtering for you, but that would require the files having special extensions, and it would interfere with diffing the files all the time, and you'd have to always want the same columns diffed.

You *could* write a program that does your customized diff and set `GIT_EXTERNAL_DIFF` to point to this program.

Comment: I went with the `diff <(git show | awk) <(git show | awk)` solution. The extra info helped in making this decision. I'll think about creating an alias if this need happens often enough. Thanks.