# Is there a git rev spec that specifies the staged file(s)?

Tags: git

So that I can keep a script implementation simpler, I'd like to do something like:

```
diff <(git show HEAD:file | awk ...) <(git show STAGED:file | awk ...)
```

Is there a rev spec that specifies the staged file?

Comment: `git diff --cached` perhaps? Or, alternatively `git diff --staged`? The two are equivalent...

Comment: `git show :0:file` from gitrevisions -  "A colon, optionally followed by a stage number (0 to 3) and a colon, followed by a path, names a blob object in the index at the given path. A missing stage number (and the colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry."

Comment: @twalberg, I want only part of the lines considered in the diff. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956715/how-to-get-git-diff-within-a-regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the Git Revision Man page](https://kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitrevisions.html)  you can achieve what you want with

```
git show :0:file
```

Unless you are in the middle of a merge :0: or just : should work for you.

> ::, e.g. :0:README, :README A colon, optionally followed by a
>   stage number (0 to 3) and a colon, followed by a path, names a blob
>   object in the index at the given path. A missing stage number (and the
>   colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry. During a merge, stage 1
>   is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch’s version
>   (typically the current branch), and stage 3 is the version from the
>   branch which is being merged.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything under `.git/refs` that references staged objects.

However, you can:

```
$ git stash file
$ diff <(git show HEAD:file | awk ...) <(git show stash:file | awk ...)
$ git stash apply
```