# How to grep the git diff to ignore changes without a certain keyword?

Tags: git

I need to do an inverse `git diff` after a refactor (where I changed the logging library), to find a few lines unrelated to the main refactor that I need to commit sepearately. I've read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462538/how-to-grep-the-git-diff) and the `-G` flag looks promising but how to inverse that? i.e. changes that don't include the string `log`.

Comment: `-G` accepts a regex, so write a regex for "does not contain 'log'".

Comment: I don't think there is an easy way to achieve that, the closest could be: git diff --unified=0 (to get rid of most of the clutter) then pipe the result of that into a inverse match like so: grep -v "log"

Answer (score 3):

Use your [pager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terminal_pager) for this sort of task. Your pager is the program that allows you to go through the output of things like `git diff` and `git log` and many, many other commands a page at a time. It has powerful features for searching, and those features work regardless of the underlying command.

The usual pager these days is [`less`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Less_(Unix)), a play on the previous default `more`. `man less` will allow you read about all its features, including...

```
   /pattern
          Search  forward  in  the  file  for the N-th line containing the pattern.  N
          defaults to 1.  The pattern is a regular expression, as  recognized  by  the
          regular  expression  library  supplied by your system.  The search starts at
          the first line displayed (but see the -a and -j options, which change this).

          Certain  characters  are special if entered at the beginning of the pattern;
          they modify the type of search rather than become part of the pattern:

          ^N or !
                 Search for lines which do NOT match the pattern.
```

So `/` then `!` and you'll see `Non-match /`. Then type `log` or whatever you want to skip. `less` will still highlight all the instances of `log`, but you can move forward and back through all the non-matching lines with `n` and `N`.

---

A better solution is to `git add` just those lines separately using `git add -p`. This will allow you to stage individual hunks of the change one at a time, skipping changes or entire files. Then commit just those pieces. See [Interactive Staging in the Git Book](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Interactive-Staging).