# Restrict size of hunks in git add -p

Tags: git, version-control

Is there a way in Git on the command line, or in a Git-GUI supported by Linux, to do git add -p for ONLY hunks that meet the two following conditions?

1. the hunk involves changes of 50+ lines.
2. the changes are only additions; no deletions

OR

How do I sort the hunks by their size?

Either option would help me achieve my goal:

I am merging two git branches, and my goal is to only look at the big hunks in one of the branches and decide whether to merge them or not. I don't want to use any of the hunks that don't meet the two above conditions, but be able to choose which hunks I add that do meet these two conditions.

I saw this question, and it makes me pessimistic, but here I don't need a regex, and I need to somehow figure out which hunks are added versus rejected.

[Add patch in git, all hunks matching regex in file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13192594/add-patch-in-git-all-hunks-matching-regex-in-file)

Comment: To my knowledge this is not currently possible out of the box in the plain CLI. Is it too much work to go through all the hunks?

Comment: Yes, there are tens of thousands.

Comment: Holy cow. o___O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built in.  However, `git add -p` is a Perl program; if you are fluent in Perl it will be easy to hack it into the code.  Just take each diff hunk and apply a test subroutine to it, and add it if it passes the test rather than if an interactive query to the user says "yes".