# How to only show git diff hunks that match regular expression

Tags: git

I can get commits that show a particular change with

```
git log --oneline -G"#define *VAR_1"
```

Is there a way *only* show the hunks that contain that change.  I tried

```
git diff --no-ext-diff -G"#define *VAR_1"
```

but it shows all the hunks in all files that contain that search term.

Comment: I found [Nage Kiran's suggestiong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35434714/745903) with `grepdiff` to work. All of the native git solutions I've tried would for some reason not do.