# git-diff just over hunks matching regexp

Tags: regex, git, filtering, git-diff

Is there any option for `git diff` that allows to **just consider hunks that match some specific criteria** (e.g. a regular expression)?

I want diff to just show me hunks that, for example, start with line matching the regex `.*<<<special_diff.*` and end with a line matching the regex `.*\sspecial_diff>>>`

I am looking for solutions that would allow to do that, keeping performance fast and staying simple.

**Note:** it should be able to match multiple lines, so that I could match (into a hunk) a multiline block of text between specific delimiters.

Matching just if a hunk contains a full block (open + close delimiters); for example matching a multiline block delimited by `<body>` and `</body>`.

Comment: Anonymously voting for closing a question, without even explaining why, it's pretty unfair, unethical and definitely useless for understanding what might need to be corrected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`git diff -Gregexp`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff#Documentation/git-diff.txt--Gltregexgt). Example: the commit [5c6d3a9@mimedecode](https://github.com/phdru/mimedecode/commit/5c6d3a9d9921a674883d65896bae4caadc89b789) contains 3 hunks. If I run `git diff 5c6d3a9~ 5c6d3a9` I see all 3.

I can filter them using `git diff -GReplaced 5c6d3a9~ 5c6d3a9` and I see only 2 of these 3 hunks. With `git diff -Greplaced 5c6d3a9~ 5c6d3a9` nothing is shown because by default regexp searching is case-sensitive. To make it case-insensitive add `-i`: `git diff -Greplaced -i 5c6d3a9~ 5c6d3a9`; this again produces 2 hunks.

Comment: Mmh, interesting. Could that be used to match also multiple lines? That's actually my final purpose, sorry if I didn't mention it before.

Comment: I'm not sure but I think no. I suspect `git` applies regexps on line basis, not for the entire text at once. So you can search at the beginning of a line but not at the beginning of the hunk.

Comment: Mmmh, I supposed that too . Would be great to have the chance to run some *awk* script; that way I guess it would be possible to process multiline blocks 

Comment: Then you need a tool that can process hunks. Something like [grepdiff](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35434714/7976758) or [splitpatch](https://github.com/jaalto/splitpatch).

Comment: For the record: this is wrong. `-G<regexp>` selects entire files, not hunks. Try it on that exact same commit, using `remove` for the regex - you'll see it shows both hunks from `mimedecode/mimedecode.py`. If there is a way to select individual hunks, I haven't yet found it.